# VSCode Angular TS Auto Import no longer works

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated my VSCode, and this is the newly updated version of my VSCode

```
Version 1.19.2
Commit 490ef761b76b3f3b3832eff7a588aac891e5fe80
Date 2018-01-10T15:55:03.538Z
Shell 1.7.9
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64
```

I'm not quite sure the previous version of my VSCode, but **since the update the auto import feature is not working anymore**.

For example in `app.module.ts` file (on Angular 2+ project) when i typed `FormsModule` there are no `light bulb icon` on left side bar that can be clicked to auto import `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms`, on previous version it works fine although sometimes doesn't work but after restarting vscode the problem usually fixed, but on current version the problem still persist even after restarting vscode, why is this happening? how to fix this?